# View size wrap_content dose not show in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview ( parent recyclerview ) and one more recyclerview inside. I am using relative layout to wrap the "child" recyclerview but it does not show when size of relative layout is wrap content(still showing if size of relativelayout is fixed ). this is my code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/layout_media">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/multiple_media_list"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You seems to be nesting `RecylerView`. Please post complete UI code for better understanding.

Comment: Which part do you want me to post? Thanks

Comment: Where you have done nesting of `RecyclerView`

Comment: This is an item in the "parent" recyclerview. The "parent" works fine. But, like I said in the description, wrap content attribute dose not work when I set it for the "child" recyclerview  (  still working if relativelayout's size is fixed)